# How do I go from $33/64 - 2x + x^2 \longrightarrow \bigg(x - \frac{2 + \sqrt{4 +33/16}}{2}\bigg)\bigg(x - \frac{2 - \sqrt{4 +33/16}}{2}\bigg)$?

Tags: quadratics

> How do I go from $\frac{33}{64} - 2x + x^2 \longrightarrow\bigg(x - \frac{2 + \sqrt{4 +33/16}}{2}\bigg)\bigg(x - \frac{2 - \sqrt{4 +33/16}}{2}\bigg)$ and then to $\big(x - 1-\frac{\sqrt{33}}{8}\big)\big(x - 1 + \frac{\sqrt{31}}{8}\big)?$

For the first, I know that it has something with the quadratic equation to do, but what is that? And how do I go from the second to the third?

Comment: Note that the quadratic formula is given as $x =  \dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} $ where in your case: $a = 1 , b = -2 , c = \dfrac{33}{64}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{33}{64} - 2x + x^2 \\
&= x^2 - 2x + \frac{33}{64} \\
&= x^2 - 2x + 1 - 1 + \frac{33}{64} \\
&= (x-1)^2 - 31/64 \\
&= (x-1)^2 - 31/64 \\
&= (x-1)^2 - 31/64 \\
&= \left( (x-1) - \sqrt{31}/8 \right)\cdot\left( (x-1) + \sqrt{31}/8 \right) \\
&= \color{red}{\left( x-1 - \sqrt{31}/8 \right)\cdot\left( x-1 + \sqrt{31}/8 \right)} \\
&= \left( x-\frac {2 + \sqrt{31}/4}2 \right)\cdot\left( x-\frac{2 - \sqrt{31}/4}{2} \right) \\
&= \left( x-\frac {2 + \sqrt{31/16}}2 \right)\cdot\left( x-\frac{2 - \sqrt{31/16}}{2} \right) \\
& = \left(x - \frac{2 + \sqrt{4 \color{red}-33/16}}{2}\right)\cdot\left(x - \frac{2 - \sqrt{4 \color{red}-33/16}}{2}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Please note the minus inside square roots!

Answer (score 0):

The quadratic eqation:

If $ax^2 +bx +c =0$ then

$x^2 +\frac {b }{a}x =-c/a$

$x^2 + 2\frac {b}{2a}x +\frac {b}{2a}^2 = -c/a  +\frac {b}{2a}^2=\frac {b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2} $

$(x+b/2a)^2 = \frac {b^2 - 4ac}{4a^2} $

$x+ b/2a = \pm \frac {\sqrt { b^2 - 4ac }}{2a} $

$x=\frac {-b\pm  \sqrt { b^2 - 4ac } }{2a}$

And therefore:

$ax^2 + bx+ c= a (x + \frac {b  +\sqrt { b^2 - 4ac } }{2a} )(x + \frac {b-  \sqrt { b^2 - 4ac } }{2a})$

So if $ax^2 + bx + c >0; a >0$ then $ (x + \frac {b  +\sqrt { b^2 - 4ac } }{2a} )(x + \frac {b-  \sqrt { b^2 - 4ac } }{2a}) > 0$ and either both terms are positive or both terms are negative.

The final bit is just arithmetic on fractions.

There is an error.  It should be $1 \pm \sqrt {97}/8$